# Remove first value ? object:null ? in select option Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm having problems with select option in Angularjs 
This is code in file js

```
$scope.ListOption = [];
$scope.ListOption.push({ Value: "0", Name: Car });
$scope.ListOption.push({ Value: "1", Name: House });
```

Here's what the code HTML looks like

```
<select class="form-control" id="Category" ng-model="Category">

<option ng-repeat="option in ListOption" value="{{option.Value}}">
 {{option.Name}}</option>

</select>
```

The generated html is

```
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="Category" style="padding: 0px;">
<option value="? object:null ?"></option>
<option ng-repeat="option in ListOption" value="0" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Car</option>
<option ng-repeat="option in ListOption" value="1" class="ng-binding ng-scope">House</option>
</select>
```

I have quite a headache on this issue. Looking forward to having someone help me the other way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJs tend to do this (generate extra option elment) when the value of the variable in `ng-model` doesn't match any of the values of the existing `<option>`.
You can solve it by setting an initial value (of the same type also), and it's one of the values in your `<option>` elements .
Or add one `<option>` element without `value` and with text `Select one` inside it. so it'll be selected.

```js
function MyController($scope) {
$scope.Category = "1";
$scope.ListOption = [];
$scope.ListOption.push({ Value: "0", Name: 'Car' });
$scope.ListOption.push({ Value: "1", Name: 'House' });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ng-controller="MyController">
<select class="form-control" id="Category" ng-model="Category"
  ng-options="item.Value as item.Name for item in ListOption">

</select>

{{Category}}
</div>
```

Make sure `$scope.Category` is the same type (not only value) as `Value` in `ListOption` variable, otherwise AngularJs will create extra option and select it.

Comment: I understand but what i want to be when the default load will select the Value is 0 and Name is Car, do you have any way to help me?

Comment: You're welcome :) don't forget to check as correct answer it is.

Answer (score 1):

The first option

```
<option value="? object:null ?"></option>
```

is generated because the ngModel value Category is not defined and select will match the value of Caegory with its options. Since no option is undefined, it adds a dummy option itself.

To solve this yyu can initialize the ngModel value Category to the first option automatically or add a new option with value as blank string and then initialize Category to blank string. It will also trigger your validation if any.
New options would be

```
$scope.Category = "";
$scope.ListOption = [];
$scope.ListOption.push({ Value: "", Name: "Please Select" });
$scope.ListOption.push({ Value: "0", Name: "Car" });
$scope.ListOption.push({ Value: "1", Name: "House" });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I want to be when the default load will select the Value is 0 and Name is Car, do you have any way to help me?

Answer (score 0):

As you wanted to mention the first value as default you can use ng-selected in option to set 0 as default. Below mentioned code sample for your reference.

```html
<select class="form-control" id="Category" ng-model="Category">

<option ng-repeat="option in ListOption" value="{{option.Value}}" ng-selected="option.Value == '0'">
 {{option.Name}}</option>

</select>
```